# Login dialog close everything

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, while-loop, exit

I'm trying to make an simple application in C# using Windows Forms.

My program requires the user to login. I've got the following code in the main form ( Form1 ):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserClass user = new UserClass();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        while (! user.isLoggedIn())
        {
            loginForm login = new loginForm();
            login.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, as long as the user is not logged in, the user will be presented with the `loginForm`.

I've got a cancel button on the form whose click event handler is below.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

This results in an endless loop of the `loginForm` popping up and closing.

What can I do to get rid of the endless loop and close the application when the user clicks cancel?

Is there a better way to force the user to login after staring the program?

Comment: check the DialogResult. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It would be advisable to close the form rather than using `Application.Exit();`.

Comment: @cheedep, thanks for your advise, took an look at it and looks nice. Michael Had it already written down, and that works, exept for the main form, that one is not closing...

Comment: @RyanGates, understood, using  `this.close();` now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the line added that checks the `DialogResult` that comes back from the `loginForm`. This will allow you to `break` out of this loop if the user hits `Cancel` and thus allow the `Application.Exit()` call to succeed as well.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DialogResult _loginResult;

    UserClass user = new UserClass();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        while (! user.isLoggedIn())
        {
            loginForm login = new loginForm();
            _loginResult = login.ShowDialog();
            if (_loginResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_loginResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            this.Close(); // which should shut down the app
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, that seems to work, but the mainForm won't close. I want to exit the application, and when i use `Application.Exit();` inside the if statement, the application isn't exited...

Comment: @Mathlight, please see my edit, and let me know how that works. Get rid of the `Application.Exit()` on the login form.

Comment: Nope, that didn't worked. I'm using `this.close` now on the cancel button in the login form, instead of the `Application.Exit();` but the main Form is still showing...

Comment: @Mathlight, this is probably related to the fact that it's in the constructor -please see my edit.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! But can you help me explaining why? Do you override every OnShown, or only the login.OnShown?

Comment: @Mathlight, I only needed to do it here because we needed to evaluate the result from the `loginForm`. You don't need to override every `OnShown`. In fact, this would be quite uncommon -except in cases like this. But for me to close the main form `Form1` I needed the Windows message pump to respond -and that couldn't happen in the `.ctor`.

Comment: ALright, thank you again verry verry much. Have an nice day ;)

Answer (score 1):

this code:

```
     while (! user.isLoggedIn())
    {
        loginForm login = new loginForm();
        login.ShowDialog();
    }
```

says that if the user isn't logged in, show the dialog, if they cancel the dialog (close without logging in) it'll just show them a new one due to the loop.

Why not change the while loop to an if statement?

Comment: Because if somehow they manage to close the loginform without realy login, the program will crash ( mayby ). That's why ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the new'ing outside the loop

```
loginForm login = new loginForm();

while (! user.isLoggedIn())
    {
        if (login.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
              Close();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Michael Perrenoud Already answerd the question Thirdy. But thanks for thinking with us ;)